# performSelector in category of superclass fails when calling method available in specific subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, nsattributedstring, objective-c-category

I have UIView category that defines methods to manipulate `attributedText` property of UILabel and UITextView.

```
@implementation UIView (replaceAttrText)
-(void) replaceAttrText: (NSString *)str {
    if ([self respondsToSelector: @selector(setAttributedText)]) {
        NSMutableAttributedString *labelText = [self template];

        // change it

        [self performSelector:@selector(setAttributedText) withObject: labelText];
    }
}
@end
```

respondsToSelector returns false for both UILabel and UITextView (although they respond to setAttributedText) and if setAttributedText is executed directly without `respondsToSelector` check an exception is raised.

When category is implemented directly on UILabel (without selectors) everything works, but unfortunately UILabel and UITextView don't have common ancestor that has attributedText property.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Extending Apple provided classes in this fashion is generally a sign that your architecture is extremely fragile and your program is going to be difficult to maintain.  That method will silently do nothing for classes that don't implement `setAttributedText:`.  You really should know what you are talking to, quite specifically, at the time you are talking to it.

Comment: @bbum I could have implemented these method by extending NSAttributedText, probably, but it would require an extra assignment every time those methods are called and I also use [NSObject's hash] to cache control's original values... After JavaScript adding a bit of flexibility to iOS doesn't feel unsafe.

Comment: You aren't writing JavaScript anymore.  You are using Objective-C and the iOS frameworks.  Applying a pattern from a different language that is explicitly recommended against by Apple may be immediately convenient, but it will lead to a world of pain.   BTW:  If you really *really* think this is a good idea, at least prefix your method with `esp_` so you don't collide with some random future update that might add the same method.

Comment: Yes, starting to like Objective-C after a week of intense hate, gradually turning into attraction :) The last idea is a good one, thanks, I can use my common class prefix to prefix category methods too... But how would you do what I need otherwise - I need methods to manipulate attributedText of two classes of controls that have no common ancestor with such property? Create category for NSAttributedText instead?

Comment: Answer beyond the 600 characters of a comment added. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`UILabel` and `UITextView` do not have a method named `setAttributedText`. But they do have a method named `setAttributedText:`. Note the colon. The colon is part of the method name. Having it or not represents two completely separate methods.

Change your code to:

```
-(void) replaceAttrText: (NSString *)str {
    if ([self respondsToSelector: @selector(setAttributedText:)]) {
        NSMutableAttributedString *labelText = [self template];

        // change it

        [self performSelector:@selector(setAttributedText:) withObject: labelText];
    }
}
```

In other words, add a colon to both references to `setAttributedText`.

Comment: That was it, I never used selectors before... Thanks a lot!

Comment: Right concrete answer; wrong pattern.  At least prefix that method.

Answer (score 3):

@maddy has the right specific answer.  This addresses what is considered an anti-pattern.

In general, you shouldn't extend Apple provided classes using categories.  Doing so means that your code is effectively intertwined with the system frameworks.  This makes maintenance and enhancements more difficult in that you'll end up having to not only deal with your own classes, but also refactor your code that -- through intertwinement -- has an implementation that is in the patterns of both the class it extends and the classes that use it.

This is why Apple generally recommends against these kinds of patterns.   If you *do* extend Apple classes, you should never override existing methods (breaks implementation details) and you should **always** prefix your methods with a prefix such that future releases of the OS -- even updates -- don't happen to include a method that collides with yours (it has happened before -- `addObjectIfAbsent:` on `NSMutableArray` was the most notable such event).

As well, the sometimes-does-the-work-sometimes-does-not behavior of checking `isKindOfClass:` or `respondsToSelector:` is another anti-pattern.   A well architected application should generally avoid passing around types so generic that the receiver of the type has to figure out what it is before it can operate on it.   Doing this defeats the compilers ability to double-check code correctness, amongst other things.

I would suggest that you refactor your application such that your UI objects that need attributed text are accessible via one means and those that don't by another.   I.e. whatever calls `replaceAttrText:` (also, in Objective-C, abbreviations are rarely used.  The IDE's completion makes it rare that you need to type anything out and the lack of abbreviations leads to code clarity) would only do so on objects that truly need to have their attributed text adjusted.   If you are dynamically or programmatically generating your user interface, you might have a controller object that sits between the model and the views that handles this, for example.

Comment: -addObjectIfAbsent: was fun. IIRC some developers implemented it and returned `void`, and NeXT returned `BOOL` (depending on whether the object had actually been added). The collision didn't merely change the behaviour, it _corrupted the stack_ at the call site. Plenty of fun to debug.

Comment: What is good about X-Code is that changing interfaces is really easy. Not like with JavaScript, where you should NEVER change method names :)

Comment: @GrahamLee Corrupted the underlying persistent store in EOF, too!